# Best way to get method parameter names and values into dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-application-insights

I am currently adding some logging to our application to aid debugging in the future. To achieve this I have written a  DLL with a static class which basically acts as a layer between our application and writes to the chosen log source, this is normally application insights.

One of the things I want to achieve is to log a trace to application insights with the method name and parameters, now this is achievable with code like this:

```
var methodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;    
var methodParameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Parameter1", "Parameter1 Value" }, { "Parameter2", "Parameter2 Value" } };
appInsightsClient.TrackTrace(methodName, methodParameters);
```

and this works fine.

I am wondering if there is a better / cleaner way to achieve this? For methods with lots of parameters this will easily become difficult to read. I know that MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() has a method for GetParameters() but these do not return the value. This is also relies on the developer setting the methodParameters / methodName variables back to null so they are picked up by garbage collection and with lots of methods being hit, I don't want to consume too much memory.

I appreciate this question is partly subjective and the opinion of the individual developer, but I can't seem to find any alternatives or examples out there, and can't be the only person who does this.

Comment: Hi. I am using MediatR with https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors 
This let me Audit log Requests that requires me to log. Otherwise you should wrap your method in some kind of Action method that saves input / output.

Comment: Where are the values coming from? In your example you "hard coded them".

Comment: @MrPaulch The names would have to be hard-coded and the value would just be the parameter itself.

Comment: @Kiksen I will look into this repo thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it is using an [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) framework. I know at least a couple of them. One is [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), which is really feature rich but isn't free. The other one I've experience with is [MrAdvice](https://github.com/ArxOne/MrAdvice).

Basically what you can do with those framework is create method interception points. You can apply custom logic when a method is entered and exited. What you could do is inspect the method info and use that in the logging. You can decorate the methods you are interested in so you have control over which methods are logged or not logged.

For example, using MrAdvice you can do something like:

```cs
public sealed class AppInsightsRequestAttribute : Attribute, IMethodAsyncAdvice
    {
        private static readonly TelemetryClient TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);

        public async Task Advise(MethodAsyncAdviceContext context)
        {
            var parameters = context.TargetMethod.GetParameters();
            var parameterDescription = string.Join(", ",
                parameters.Select(p => $"{p.ParameterType.Name} {p.Name}"));
            var signature = $"{context.Target ?? context.TargetType}.{context.TargetName}({parameterDescription})";

            using (var operation = TelemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>(signature))
            {
                try
                {
                    await context.ProceedAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    EnrichRequestTelemetry(operation.Telemetry, context, parameters);
               }
            }
        }

        private static void EnrichRequestTelemetry(ISupportProperties telemetry, MethodAsyncAdviceContext context, IReadOnlyList<ParameterInfo> parameters)
        {
            telemetry.Properties.Add(
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Accessibility", 
                    context.TargetMethod.Attributes.ToVisibilityScope().ToString()));

            for (var i = 0; i < context.Arguments.Count; i++)
            {
                telemetry.Properties.Add($"ARG {parameters[i].Name}", context.Arguments[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will create a RequestTelemetry item and send it to application insights. The `EnrichRequestTelemetry` method will add the method arguments and values as custom properties to the item.

You can then decorate your methods like this: (there are more options, but this is to demonstrate a possibility)

```cs
public class SomeClass
    {
        [AppInsightsRequest]
        public async Task<string> SayHello(string to)
        {
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
            string response = null;

            try
            {
                var greeting = $"Hello {to}";
                telemetryClient.TrackTrace($"Sending {greeting}");

                response = await SomeService.SendAsync(greeting);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                telemetryClient.TrackException(exception);
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

A complete sample using a console application to send telemetry to application insights can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/Ibis-Software/AppInsightsDemo/tree/master/src/NonWebIntegrationDemo) which I created.